# Need help get following query

Tags: mysql, sum

I have three tables customer, customer_account, account_transaction

Table structure is as follow -

**Customer**

```
Id,
Branch,
Name
```

..

**customer_account**

```
Id,
Cust_id,
Loanamout,
EMI
```

**account_transaction**

```
ID,
account_id,
amount,
date
```

I need to get branch wise details in form of count of Loan given, sum of loan given, and sum of emi received for a particular branch. below is my current query -

```
SELECT
  count(s.id) as cntloan, 
  SUM(s.Loanamout)
  (
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM account_transaction i
    WHERE s.id = i.account_id
  ) AS curbal 
From
   customer as c,
   customer_account as s
where c.branch = 1 and s.cust_id = c.id
```

It is giving me desired result for count of loan and sum of loan given. but not giving the right sum of EMI paid by customers

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks you very much

Comment: I don't see EMI in that query. Where are you working it out / retrieving it?

Comment: Is this for a midterm? This is a very basic database class question.

Comment: While formatting, I notice a missing comma beore the subquery. We assume that was a typo...

Answer (score 0):

This SQL has aggregative functions such as count and sum, so without a group by, this would not work.

```
SELECT customer.id,
COUNT(customer_account.id) as cntloadn,
SUM(customer_account.loan) as loan,
SUM(account_transaction.amount)
FROM customer
JOIN customer_account ON customer_account.cust_id = customer.id
JOIN account_transaction ON account_transaction.account_id = customer_account.id
GROUP BY customer.id
```